# Download attachments from Gmail using NodeJS (API)

Tags: javascript, node.js, gmail, attachment

How to download attachments from Gmail using NodeJS and JS? Is there only 1 way - using OAuth2?

Hi there!
i hope someone could help me. I want to download Excel attachments from Gmail and save them in some folder.
How to do it? Which libraries could i use? I heart about node-imap or imap-simple to get files.

Also I watched Youtube and realised that i will be able to use only way with OAuth2 parameters in my code.

Maybe someone created such script recently and could share with me some hints.... I would be very grateful!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a good place to ask for complete examples or existing solutions. What have you tried for yourself? What issues did you run into? I suggest looking into online tutorials for accessing email from node.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your advice:) Finally ive done it,but using Power Automate and Google OneDrive.